# I keep receiving the unhashable error when trying to deal with Turn Order?

Tags: python

So I am trying to create a small turnbased program and I came up with some code to determine the player's turn order just fine. However when I tried to do determine the enemies' based upon the players', I ran into a problem. It keeps returining the unhashable error to me. Is there a way to deal with that so I get my desired result, or if you have a better solution for my problem please let me know. Here is the code:

```
Pm1Order = random.randint(1,8) 
Pm2Order = random.randint(1,8)
if Pm2Order == Pm1Order: 
    Pm2Order = Pm1Order - 1
    if Pm2Order == 0:
        Pm2Order = Pm1Order + 1
Pm3Order = random.randint(1,8) 
if Pm3Order == Pm2Order:
    Pm3Order = Pm1Order - 2
    if Pm3Order == 0:
        Pm3Order = Pm1Order + 2
Pm4Order = random.randint(1,8)
if Pm4Order == Pm3Order:
    Pm4Order = Pm1Order - 3
    if Pm4Order == 0:
        Pm4Order = Pm1Order + 3
print("The turn orders for your party is " +str(Pm1Order)+ " for the knight, " +str(Pm2Order)+ " for the theif, " +str(Pm3Order)+ " for the doctor, and " +str(Pm4Order)+ " for the priest.")
PlayerOrder = set([Pm1Order , Pm2Order , Pm3Order , Pm4Order])
print(str(PlayerOrder))
FullOrder = set([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8])
EnemyOrder = FullOrder.difference(PlayerOrder)
EnemyOrder2 = FullOrder.difference(PlayerOrder)
print(str(EnemyOrder))
Enemy1Order = random.sample(set([EnemyOrder]), 1)
print(Enemy1Order)
```

---

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "foo.py", line xx, in <module>
    Enemy1Order = random.sample(set([EnemyOrder]), 1)
TypeError: unhashable type: 'set'
```

Comment: Please post the Traceback.

Comment: EnemyOrder is already a set. You don't need to call `random.sample(set([EnemyOrder]), 1)`, just call `random.sample(EnemyOrder, 1)`.

Answer (score 0):

[set.difference()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.difference) returns a set so `EnemyOrder` is already a set. Try

```
Enemy1Order = random.sample(EnemyOrder, 1)
```

Or

```
Enemy1Order = random.sample(set(*[EnemyOrder]), 1)
```